# I want to know fuction return type in given code below.....and explain how this code works?

Tags: c

Explain the return type of the function given below and how to call this fuction

```
// C function to search a given key in a given BST
struct node* search(struct node* root, int key) 
{
  // Base Cases: root is null or key is present at root
  if (root == NULL || root->key == key)
    return root;

  // Key is greater than root's key
  if (root->key < key)
    return search(root->right, key);

  // Key is smaller than root's key
  return search(root->left, key);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Usually we don't like if you just through an assignment question at us. Please work through the "help" to see  what questions to ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function's return type is `struct node*`, i.e. a pointer to `struct node` type. It will return a node for a given key.

You can call it as

```
search(root, key); // 'root' is root of the tree and 'key' is the data you want to search.
```

Answer (score 0):

This function searches a tree for a node with a given key. When that node is found it is returned. The function accepts the root of the tree and the key to search for. Nodes in trees usually contain a value and pointers to all the node's descendants. So in your case of a binary tree it contains pointers to the left and right descendants.

In order to call this function you need to first construct a tree and save the pointer to its root. Then you call this function with the root and the key you are searching for.

Comment: i couldn't understand this   struct node* search(struct node* root, int key)

Comment: What about it? struct node is just another way of writing node. Depends on how the struct was defined.